# Immutability as applied to classes

Tags: c#, immutability

I have been reading about immutable types, and how that it is not recommended to have a mutable struct.

What if I have a class instead:

```
public class Vector
{
    public double X, Y;

    public void Rotate(double angle) 
    {
        double x = this.X; double y = this.Y;
        this.X = (float)((Math.Cos(angle) * x) - (Math.Sin(angle) * y)); 
        this.Y = (float)((Math.Sin(angle) * x) + (Math.Cos(angle) * y)); 
    }
}
```

So this will be called as:

```
Vector v = new Vector(1,0);
v.rotate(Math.PI / 2.0);
```

In this case, should I have written like this instead?

```
public class Vector
{
    public double X, Y;

    public Vector Rotate(double angle) 
    {
        double x = this.X; double y = this.Y;
        return new Vector((float)((Math.Cos(angle) * x) - (Math.Sin(angle) * y)), (float)((Math.Sin(angle) * x) + (Math.Cos(angle) * y)));
    }
}
```

To be called as:

```
Vector v = new Vector(1,0);
Vector v2 = v.rotate(Math.PI / 2.0);
```

Comment: that depends on your use cases - if it's just for the immutability then yes of course you need the second version - to be sure you should mark `X` and `Y` as `readonly` (or at least only provide public getters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, an immutable class will return a new instance when you create a new version. That's how all `String` methods work, for example.

However, you should also make sure that the properties can't be changed from the outside. Also, there is no reason to cast the coordinates down to `float` when the properties are `double`:

```
public class Vector
{

    public double X { get; private set; }
    public double Y { get; private set; }

    public Vector(double x, double y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public Vector Rotate(double angle) 
    {
        double x = this.X; double y = this.Y;
        return new Vector(((Math.Cos(angle) * x) - (Math.Sin(angle) * y)), ((Math.Sin(angle) * x) + (Math.Cos(angle) * y)));
    }
}
```